# c++ how to exclude random numbers that have already been tried

Tags: c++, random, switch-statement

I'm writing a program that has atoms moving in a lattice, which does so by picking a random number associated with a certain direction (of which there are eight) testing if that direction is viable and if not picking a new random number.

I'm wondering if there's a way to exclude that random number from the pool of random numbers that can be picked so that the program doesn't repeatedly try and pick the same random number

I'm currently using a switch that looks a bit like this (not including whole function as at the moment it's pretty huge...

```
int a = rand()%8;
    switch (a)
{case 0:
   ...
case 1:
   ...
and so forth
}
```

Comment: Keep track of the numbers you do use (e.g. in a `std::set`) and each iteration keep generating random numbers until you get a new one.

Comment: What happens after it picks eight numbers?

Comment: Do it the other way round: keep options in an array. After choosing and discarding one, "delete" it by exchanging it with the number at the end of the array and for the next iteration generate a number in [0, 7) instead of [0, 8). This way you are guaranteed to get a result in 8 tries at most, or else know that no result is acceptable.

Comment: I agree with Jonathan Potter

Comment: Sounds like you're creating a random permutation.

Comment: Put your numbers in a container, use `std::shuffle` on it.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Or a `random_shuffle`?

Comment: do you only have to remember the tried options of 1 atom at a time or of many atoms (are you for instance trying one option for "every" atom in you lattice and then backtracking if that doesn't work out)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using a vector of int containing number 1 to 8 and then randomly shuffle it after each iteration? Like:

```
std::vector<int> vOneToEight;
for (int i=1; i<9; ++i) vOneToEight.push_back(i); // {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}.
std::random_shuffle(vOneToEight.begin(), vOneToEight.end()); // 1 to 8 with random order.
for (size_t i=0; i<vOneToEight.size(); ++i)
    your_func(vOneToEight[i]); // Use the outcome in whatever way.
std::random_shuffle(vOneToEight.begin(), vOneToEight.end()); // Re-shuffle.
for (size_t i=0; i<vOneToEight.size(); ++i)
    your_func(vOneToEight[i]); // Keep going if needed..
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

**The code below was written with notepad *extremely fast*. If you find an error, please leave a comment, thanks!**

```
/* main.cpp */
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

typedef std::vector<int> NumberList;
int main()
{
    NumberList list;

    int Last = 0;

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        // Prevent using it two times in a row
        while( ( x = rand()%mod ) != last ){ }

        // Prevent adding the same number two times in the list
        bool alreadyIn == false;
        for( std::vector<int>::iterator it = list.begin(); 
             it != list.end(); it->next() )
        {
            if( *it == x )
                alreadyIn = true;
        }
        if( !alreadyIn )
            list.push_back(x);

        // Do stuff with x
        switch(x)
        {
            // ...
        }

        // Keep track of x
        last = x;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code will probably result to a list:
{ 1,0,2,4,9 }

That means that **0 WILL NOT** be the first item.

To fix that use `int Last = -1;`

** Provided that rand() returns positive integers.